# How to move/copy all databases with users, schema and roles from one server to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I need to move/copy all of my databases (only 5) from one server to another. I know how to make backup and restore but I also need to move all information of my databases including users, schema, etc…

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are two possibilities to copy database:

1 BACKUP-RESTORE
In this case you will have some probles main of which is `After you move databases to a new server, users may not be able to log in to the new server.` A solution of this problem is provided here:

[How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133/eng)

2 [DETACH-COPY-ATTACH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx) it's just copying (or moving) of database files to another server.

About pros and cons of each approach you can read here [SQL Server backup/restore v.s. detach/attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610113/sql-server-backup-restore-v-s-detach-attach)

Comment: This seems to complex to move logins

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the DB
2. Click on tasks
3. Click on generate scripts
4. Go through the wizard and select your tables
5. On the options page click the Advanced button (It's there, just doesn't stand out very well)
6. Change the "Types of data to script" option

There are options to script data and logins (a ton of other stuff). It's very handy.

Here's the script that will generate a script to add all roles on all databases

```
declare @selectStatement varchar(1000)

set @selectStatement = 'Use ?;SELECT ''USE ?''; SELECT ' + '''EXECUTE sp_AddRoleMember ''''' + ''' + roles.name + '''''''+','''''+''' +  Replace(users.name,''DOMAINA'',''DOMAINB'') + ''' + '''''''
     from sys.database_principals users
    inner join sys.database_role_members link
    on link.member_principal_id = users.principal_id
   inner join sys.database_principals roles
     on roles.principal_id = link.role_principal_id'

                            --where users.name like ''%%'''

                EXEC sp_MSForEachDB @selectStatement;
```

Comment: But this option does not add newly created login which are database agnostics.

Comment: did you the select the option to script the logins.  Are you talking about security level Logins?  I have a script to generate that as well.

Comment: Yes I am talking about security level Logins

Comment: Surround each `?` in the script above with brackes (i.e. `[?]`) to support database names containing things such as dots.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Red Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) for this task. I cost a little bit but it is worth of every penny. Note that SQL Compare does not migrate physical databases, only the content of the databases.

Comment: and... solution for postgres with the same condition (move data bases, roles, schemas, usres, etc.. (ALL!)) maybe ``pg_dumpall`` ? but how without files, just DIRECTLLY from serverA to serverB. is possible?