# How to extract sql dump from mdf file which is attached to SQL Server management studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dump

I really need to extract full sql dump with tables recreate and all data inserts from my mdf file. Any help on this will be highly apreciated.

I already tried to download mssql publishing wizard but I have no idea where to find it and how to use it.

Comment: Make a backup and restore on the other server..

Comment: Can you define more exactly what you want? Do you want scripts of all tables  of a particular database and their data?

Comment: i have one database on my hosting. so i need to put two mdf files in one database. So i just thinking to extract MDF into sql and run queries or use any other method. I tried to import data, but storage procedures was not imported in that way.

Comment: I need full sql script from mdf. with all data and procedures views and so on. I already atached one mdf to my hosting database, so i need to find out the way how to atach the other one. would be really nice to get some advice on this.

Comment: This is an answer for your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/8441434/883286.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SQL Server Management Studio you can right click on your database and select:

```
Tasks -> Generate Scripts
```

This will allow to select what tables, sp, etc you wish to take to the other database.

Simply proceed through the wizard. **Make sure to set 'Script Data' to TRUE** when prompted to choose the script options. Once the script is generated execute the script on the second database.

[image]

[image]