# Backup as bak file or Attach/Detach of SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server backup/restore v.s. detach/attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610113/sql-server-backup-restore-v-s-detach-attach)

Is there any difference in backing up a SQL Server database using .bak file or detaching the file?

We can restore both. Attaching/Detaching the files may be better as I need to copy only mdf file.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables yep its duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can backup the database online, but detach/attach require to stop working with database for users.

Add: Here are many reasons [to use backup vs detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx)

Comment: I use VSS so I can copy while its online.

Comment: Are you sure? Because you cannot detach database while some application works with it.

Comment: yep. VSS create a snapshot of drive and any file can be copied. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy

Comment: Marked as Answer for the excellent link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The mdf file will also need the ldf file to be copied, or creation of a new one on restore